# How do boolean operators work in 'if' conditions?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, operators

I am currently new to Python and am trying to run a few simple lines of code. I cannot understand how Python is evaluating this syntax after the *if* statement. Any explanations will be appreciated.

```
number = int(raw_input("Enter number : "))

if number == (1 or 2 or 3):
    print "Match"
else:
    print "No match"
```

Only the integer 1 yield a positive result and any other numbers including 2 and 3 go through the *else* branch. Can the conditions be stated as the following only?:

```
if number == 1 or number == 2 or number == 3:
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has boolean values, such as `True` and `False`, [and it also has *falsy* values](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), such as any empty list, tuple, or dictionary, an empty string, `0`, and `None`.  Truthy values are the opposite of that, namely anything that's defined.

Python's `or` [evaluates and short-circuts](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) on the **first** element that returns a truthy value.

So, the expression `(1 or 2 or 3)` is going to return `1`.

If you want to compare against *all* elements, then you're looking for the `in` keyword:

```
if number in (1, 2, 3):
    # Do logic
```

Comment: Thank you for the information and the links. I did not know of this crucial distinction of "truthy" and "falsy" values, and the whole thing makes much more sense now. If the first value is pretty much anything, then the rest of the series of Boolean operators will be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want:

```
if number in (1, 2, 3):
```

Answer (score 2):

The `or` operator takes two arguments, on its left and right sides, and performs the following logic:

> 1. Evaluate the stuff on the left-hand side.
> 2. If it is a truthy value (e.g, `bool(x) is True`, so it's not zero, an empty string, or `None`), return it and stop.
> 3. Otherwise, evaluate the stuff on the right-hand side and return that.

As such, `1 or 2 or 3` is simply `1`, so your expression turns into:

```
if number == (1):
```

If you actually mean `number == 1 or number == 2 or number == 3`, or `number in (1, 2, 3)`, you'll need to say that.

(Incidentally: The `and` operator works the same way, except step 2 returns if the left-hand-side is falsey.)